# where to find "_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" source-code file in VisualStudio webapp project?

Tags: blazor

In a Blazor clientside ASp.Core webapp in VS2019 preview there is a script-reference in index.thml file, ie:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

where can I find the blazor.webassembly.js file reference?

The index.html page contains:

```
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9):

This file is located as the resource in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build` nuget package. It is copied during build from that Nuget package to final location.

Source code for that files located https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web.JS/src

Comment: That link is not valid anymore (404 Not Found)

Comment: That link is not valid anymore (404 Not Found)  +1

Comment: Update the link guys.

Comment: let me get it breh

Answer (score 2):

The minified version can be found in your project, after building:

```
 ...\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\dist\_framework\
```